# How to move selected code segment to the left in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The question is, how do I move the selected block of code by one or several tabs, but not to the right (which is done by selecting a code and pressing Tab key), but to the left? Without selection each line one by one and deleting whitespace?

Moving parts of code from one place to another with differences in indent levels is a bit hard without knowing the shortcut.

[What I mean (Imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETWTd.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Does Shift+Tab work for you?

Comment: what @defaultlocale said, and if you dont want to single select every row, try `ALT` + `SHIFT` and select every row with the arrow keys.

Comment: Yeah, that works, thank you guys! Will remember all the shortcuts! :)

Comment: @DmitryPolovinkin please submit an answer to your question (it's okay to answer your own questions) and then mark it as accepted - it'll help others with the same problem as you had, as they'll see it's been answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For what you want,

> Shift+Tab

should do the trick. However, I would like to recommend this extension which I find easier to use when formatting blocks of text: [Indent One space](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.indent-one-space)

Note however this extension only indents selections ***by exactly one space***, forward or backwards.

[image]